# Conditional expression inside Convert.ToString() evaluating wrong?

Tags: c#

I'm stumped. Why wouldn't the first and fourth lines evaluate to null?

[image: null wut]

**Post-answer edit:**

For the benefit of others, the desired behavior would be created by using:

```
boolFoo ? null : Convert.ToString(DBNull.Value)
```

This works because `Convert.ToString()` and `null` imply a common type of `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN's documentation for the [`?:` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

> Either the type of `first_expression` and `second_expression` must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

In this case, it looks like `null` is being implicitly converted to `System.Object`. From a little further digging into MSDN's documentation, [`Convert.ToString(Object value)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh.aspx) returns [`String.Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx) if `value` is `null`.

This is not the same as in the sixth line in your post, as `Convert.ToString(null)` does *not* implicitly convert `null` to `System.Object` (since you are not using the `?:` operator).

Comment: Not in the sixth line where it evaluates Convert.ToString(null) as null and not String.Empty. [Disregard this; it was written before you changed your comment.]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they do evaluate to `null`, but `Convert.ToString(object)` returns `null` values as `String.Empty`.

**Edit per OP's comment**

In the case of `Convert.ToString(string)`, the string is simply returned, even if `null`.  Courtesy of [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/):

```
public static string ToString(string value)
{
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Not in the sixth line where it evaluates Convert.ToString(null) as null and not String.Empty.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToString((DBNull)null)` calls the `Convert.ToString(object)` overload, which [returns an empty string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) if it is passed a null. This is why the first and fourth lines evaluate to an empty string.

`Convert.ToString(null)` calls the `Convert.ToString(string)` overload, since that is the most derived applicable version. That overload [returns the argument unchanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). This is why the sixth line evaluates to null.

Answer (score 0):

They are `null`, it's just their type that is `DBNull`.

Comment: Their type is not DBNull; it is string.